# Unable to link array to dropdown box so that file link works

Tags: php, arrays, hyperlink

Here is my file.php that I have the problem with.
The opendir will show various .php files in a dropdown box but when clicking on them, it results in a 404 error.
There is obviously something wrong with either the javascript part or the php part. 
**Assuming my website is called www.mywebsite.com** and **the folder containing the .php files is called photos**, here's what I have:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function download(d) {
if (d !== '') {
    window.open('www.mywebsite.com/' + d, '_self');
}
}
</script>
</head
<body>

<?php
$dir = opendir('./photos');
echo '<select name="download" onchange="download(this.value)">';

while ($read = readdir($dir))
{

if ($read!='.' && $read!='..')
{
echo '<option value='.$read.'">'.$read.'</option>';
}

}

echo '</select>';

closedir($dir); 
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas why it's not working for me, please??

Comment: It's an html question. You can't have a link in side an option element.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is an HTML question.
You cannot use `a` tag inside an `option` tag as they have different behaviours.

The right usage would be to set the value attribute of the option tag.

```
<option value="'.$read.'">'.$read.'</option>
```

Then you can use JS or adding a button to submit the data to a server side file that would handle the redirection.

Comment: thank you for your attempt to help but it is now worse.  I now get an error and have not yet created a button:

<?php
$dir = opendir('../photos');
echo '<select>';

while ($read = readdir($dir))
{

if ($read!='.' && $read!='..')
{
echo '<option value="'.$read.'">'.$read.'</option>'';
}

}

echo '</select>';

closedir($dir); 
?>

result now is:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/content/96/10934496/html/photos/test2.php on line 40

Where do I include a button - on a separate form or in the PHP file?

Comment: It's part of the process of debugging ;) Please update the original question and add the updated code and error you're receiving, it's uncomfortable to read code in the comments section. Please also mention which line is **line 40**